# Liferay 6.2 Create site from site template issue

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, database-migration, portal

We recently upgraded Liferay from 6.1 to 6.2 including data migration. So far I've noticed something strange, when I create a new site or organization and enable propagation of changes from site template, the action of site creation seems like entering in an infinite loop and never finishes.

Can this [Reset and Propagate](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/using-site-templates-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-03-en) feature be somehow corrupted after migration?
Any help is really appreciated.